# How do I draw faces between many sets of vertices at once?

Tags: vertices, faces

I am trying to make faces between multiple sets of vertices simultaneously.

Specifically, I am attempting to do this on the ring-shaped framework in the first image; it was derived from a cylinder whose cap fill type was set to "nothing". As you can see, there is a ring of connected vertices, and another ring that was extruded above it.

[image: The ring in question.]

I am attempting to draw rectangular faces between each rectangular set of vertices. A single such rectangular face has been drawn in on the ring in the second image, below.

[image: The ring in question with one face added.]

Is it possible for me to do this *en masse* - i.e. do it across multiple faces at once, preferably across the entire ring? I have a lot of these to do and doing it individually is time-consuming (I have to do it in multiple "layers"), and I also think that it'd be useful knowledge for later projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

select only the upper vertices

[image]

press F, then x -> only faces

[image]

[image]

select 4 vertices like this:

[image]

press F

[image]

Select these 2 vertices:

[image]

then hit F as often as you need it

[image]

Comment: Is the last bit ("Select these 2 vertices then hit F as often as you need it") supposed to work without clicking - i.e. you just press F over and over again to draw in another face? The first part did, but the second part is unclear. It does nothing when I select 2 vertices and press F; the only thing that works is selecting 4 vertices at a time and then pressing F.

Comment: Never mind, figured it out, thanks. It's highlighting all the vertices and then pressing F.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE you need to activate the addon called F2 to do the F thing, but as you say, you can just press F

Comment: @moonboots I think the  behaviour of Blender's own F has been extended now? I can do this with F2 switched off.

Comment: @ Robin Betts, oh yes you're right, so maybe the OP has a previous version

Answer (score 6):

I would do this @Chris 's  way.. better feedback, you can see what you're doing.. but it's maybe worth noting that, given a set of separated edge-loops,
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops* will do its best to interpret them as a single loft:

[image]

If you are going to fill the top face as an intermediate step, then an alternative might be

1. Vertex Mode, select top, <kbd>F</kbd>,
2. Edge Mode select all, <kbd>F</kbd>,
3. Face mode, select top and bottom, <kbd>X</kbd> delete unwanted faces.

[image]

Comment: Very nice!‼️‼️‼️